# Scheduled export of data from Dynamics CRM

Tags: scheduled-tasks, dynamics-crm, export-to-csv, microsoft-dynamics

I hope someone can help me. I would like to find a way to do a scheduled *export* of select data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM (Online)

Preferably to a CSV file and have the export automated at a recurring time (at least once a day) so it does the export to a specified location without any user interaction.

I'm aware of Scribe for example but that is very expensive and I need a cheaper solution. Any ideas for scheduled and unattended exporting from Dynamics?

Comment: if you know how to code download the CRM SDK and start from there, if you don't know how to code you can hire a developer, the task isn't difficult and scribe is not required. Don't consider this comment as bad manners, but StackOverflow doesn't permit this kind of generic questions.

Answer (score 1):

As @Guido Preite mentioned, your best bet is to get the CRM SDK.  Since cost is an issue with turn-key third-party software, the SDK is a good alternative if you have a little time to get familiarized with it.  There are a lot of good examples straight from MSDN and the SDK documentation to get you up and running quickly, [start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh547453.aspx).  Basically what you could do is create a simple console app that queries the data you need, then save it off to a file.  This could then be scheduled via Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Scribe is a good solution, but isn't cheap as you say.

I've used KingswaySoft to do scheduled data imports and exports with CRM. See http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm.
It's a good product and is cheaper than Scribe. No coding is required, although you'll need some experience of SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).

Answer (score 0):

Flatly lets you auto-export data from Microsoft Dynamics Online to CSV (placed in cloud storage) every 10 minutes, hourly or daily.  It takes 5 minutes to setup.  [flatly.io](https://flatly.io)

Disclosure:  I work at Flatly.